# Java consrtuctor and toString function

Tags: java, constructor, tostring

Could you please provide the answer for the below problem

Create a class named Shipment with the following private member variables / attributes

```
int id
String shipperName
String modeOfTransportation
Float totalWeight
String arrivalPort
String departurePort
```

1. Create a private static variable nextShipmentId in Shipment class and initialise it to 1000.
2. Create a Constructor which accepts 6 arguments in the argument order (id,shipperName,modeOfTransportation,totalWeight,arrivalPort,departurePort)
3. Create a static method createNewShipment() - which accepts the shipment details in the parameter and generates the shipment object and assigns the shipment id and return the shipment object. For returning the object pass the values in the constructor and return it.
4. Display the shipment details by overriding the toString() method in Shipment class.

Use `String.format("%-15d%-15s%-25s%-15s%-20s%s",this.id,this.shipperName,this.modeOfTransportation,this.totalWeight.toString()+"Kg",this.arrivalPort,this.departurePort)`  to format the string.

Sample Input and Output :

Enter the number of shipments :
2
Enter the shipment 1 details
Enter the shipper name :
AGCI
Enter the mode of transportation :
Air
Enter the total weight :
300
Enter the arrival port :
India
Enter the departure port :
America
Enter the shipment 2 details
Enter the shipper name :
DHL Services
Enter the mode of transportation :
Water
Enter the total weight :
500
Enter the arrival port :
Cochin
Enter the departure port :
Srilanka

Shipment details are
Id   Shippername  Mode of transportation  Total weight  Arrival port  Departure port
1001 AGCI         Air                     300Kg         India         America
1002 DHL Services Water                   500Kg         Cochin        Srilanka

Comment: SO isn't a code-writing service - show us what you've done so far, and we'll help with any **specific** problems you have.

Comment: *gimme teh codez* - No.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Shipment{

    Shipment(int id, String shipperName, String modeOfTransportation,
                Double totalWeight, String arrivalPort, String departurePort){
        this.nextShipment = 1000;
        this.shipperName = shipperName;
        this.modeOfTransportation = modeOfTransportation;
        this.totalWeight = totalWeight;
        this.arrivalPort = arrivalPort;
        this.departurePort = departurePort;
    }

    public static Shipment createNewShipment(int id, String shipperName, String modeOfTransportation,
                Double totalWeight, String arrivalPort, String departurePort){

        Shipment shipment = new Shipment(id, shipperName, modeOfTransportation, totalWeight, arrivalPort, departurePort);

        return shipment;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format("%-15d%-15s%-25s%-15s%-20s%s",this.id,this.shipperName,this.modeOfTransportation,this.totalWeight.toString()+"Kg",this.arrivalPort,this.departurePort);
    }

    private int id;
    private String shipperName;
    private String modeOfTransportation;
    private Double totalWeight;
    private String arrivalPort;
    private String departurePort;
    private static int nextShipment;
}
```

Normally Stackoverflow is no code-writing service, but i had nothing to do so here is your code :)